# Any way to colour properties differently from fields?

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, resharper-8.0

Resharper 8 appears to only have a single colour setting for fields and properties, called `Resharper Field Identifier` (found in the `Fonts and Colors` section of Visual Studio's Environment settings).

So whatever colour I select for this will be used for both public properties AND private fields.

Does anyone know of a way to have separate colours for these items?

Comment: not yet, but it sure would be nice. even if properties could just be the same color but bold or something would be nice.

Comment: not for the last 8 years since it was added to their bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-72393

Comment: It looks like this is now on the backlog for fixing in Resharper 2017.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-72393#tab=History